# Integrability of the derivative of $f(x) = x^2 \sin (1/x^2)$ if $x \ne 0$ and 0 otherwise.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

why is the derivative of the function   $f(x) = x^2 \sin (1/x^2)$ if $x \ne 0$ and 0 otherwise, not integrable?

Comment: The  least you can do is compute the derivative first. Then we can think about why it is not integrable.

Comment: Have you plotted this derivative and seen what it looks like?

Comment: I have computed it in my notebook @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: @hopefully Whatever computation you have done should have come in the question itself. Remember, the more effort you show in solving your question, the more help you get here. Besides, the answer below is fine.

Comment: I actually think it can be possible to answer this without calculating the derivative, using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the fact that f(x) (as the antiderivative of its derivative ) does not follow the properties of an integral..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x \ne 0$ we have $f'(x)=2x \sin(1/x^2)-\frac{1}{x}\cos(1/x^2)$. Then:

$f'(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n \pi}})=-\sqrt{n \pi}\cos(n \pi)=(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{n \pi}$,

thus $|f'(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n \pi}})|=\sqrt{n \pi} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty.$

Similar:  $|f'(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n \pi}})|=\sqrt{n \pi} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty.$

Conclusion: if $[a,b]$ is an intervall with $0 \in [a,b]$ , then $f'$ is not bounded on $[a,b]$, hence $f'$ is not R- integrable on $[a,b]$.